# Set width of Custom Tool Panel Component

Tags: ag-grid

I have a custom tool panel component but would like to set a custom width.  I tried applying css + child selectors but no luck in setting the width of my custom component.   Are there other ways of achieving this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using CSS.

Have a look at this plunk: [Tool Panel - custom width](https://plnkr.co/edit/MmdoDo2nEvBRthxdiuOZ?p=preview)

Add below CSS for this:

```
.ag-tool-panel-wrapper {
  width: 280px !important;
}
.ag-side-bar.ag-side-bar-right {
  width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! So I have multiple sidebar components.. doing this ^^ sets width to all components but I need to set width to a specific one - I tried using nth-child(n) and nth(n)-of-type but still no luck...

Comment: @russian_cosmonaut reproduce your issue on plunk

Comment: Hey! I got it.. the solution is:

.ag-tool-panel-wrapper:nth-child(n) {
   width:300px !important;
}

Comment: There must be a way to add a custom class to the tool panel wrapper element I would assume?